# Macbook Air - CodeBlocks installed - terminal not running my code

Tags: macos, terminal, codeblocks

I have recently started studying computer science and we are to use CodeBlocks as our IDE for C++. I have installed the software on my MacBook Air. Additionally, I have downloaded Xcode.

I am trying to run the typical "Hello World" piece of code to assess if everything is set up properly and my terminal keeps on popping up with this error:

```
Last login: Wed Jul  1 08:57:00 on ttys000
'/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/jarrencollet/Desktop/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld '
jarrencollet@Jarrens-Air ~ % '/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/jarrencollet/Desktop/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld '
zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/jarrencollet/Desktop/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld 
jarrencollet@Jarrens-Air ~ %
```

I have removed my Desktop and Documents from my iCloud drive in an attempt to fix it but have had no joy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the quotes ' ' around the command. If you copy/paste the command without the quotes, it should be OK:

```
jarrencollet@Jarrens-Air ~ % /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/jarrencollet/Desktop/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld
```

I have not yet found a more satisfying fix.